# Should I use Stripe cURL API instead and use PHP to make cURL calls to Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am struggling with the Stripe PHP API. Their cURL API looks easier. Should I use Stripe cURL API instead and use PHP to make cURL calls to Stripe? If not, what are the reasons? And is it even easier?

Answer (score 1):

It is ultimately up to you what you prefer, however I highly recommend using the stripe-php library. It is at its core just an abstraction of cURL calls wrapped up with some quality of life functionality for you in an easy to use manner.

It also provides many features that you wouldn't get from cURL. For instance [automatic retries](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#configuring-automatic-retries), idempotency keys and [robust error handling](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=php). All these things you get for free with stripe-php that you'd have to implement yourself if you roll your own cURL implementation.

Even if you're struggling with the stripe-php library, I would recommend sticking with it as you'll likely run into many more problems with a homegrown cURL solution as your integration gets more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is their library and how to install it https://stripe.com/docs/libraries

Terminal:

> #Install the PHP library via Composer

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

Then there are some usage examples here
https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0

You shouldn't even be able to go around the API.
Don't invent your own curl functions and use the library.